# How to use the scan operator to count emitted values of a void observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need an observable of type void that emits the number of emitted void values.

```
const subject = new Subject<void>();

subject.pipe(
    scan((acc, curr) => acc + 1, 0)
).subscribe(count => console.log(count));

subject.next(); // should output 1
subject.next(); // should output 2
subject.next(); // should output 3
```

The above gives the following compiler error:

```
   TS2345: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<number>' is not 
      assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<void, number>'.
      Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
      Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<number>'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Maybe I'm just tired, but I can't seem to fix the error. I don't see anything wrong with my `scan()` operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve your problem, you can specify types for the parameters of the function that you pass to `scan`, like this:

```ts
subject.pipe(
  scan((acc: number, curr: void) => acc + 1, 0)
).subscribe(count => console.log(count));
```

The typings for `scan` and `reduce` need some attention. Basically, they are the way they are because they needed to be like that for older versions of TypeScript. Now that TypeScript 2.8 is the minimum supported version for RxJS 6, it should be possible to improve the typings.

Answer (score -2):

You could just use a tap

```js
const { Subject } = rxjs;
const { tap } = rxjs.operators;

const subject = new Subject();

count = 0;

subject.pipe(
    tap(() => { count++; })
).subscribe(_ => console.log(count));

subject.next(); // should output 1
subject.next(); // should output 2
subject.next(); // should output 3
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could, but to do it properly, you'd need to move the count into per-subscription state: https://link.medium.com/JJOjgF5KiU